# Typechain making me convert Buffer to string to represent solidity's bytes

Tags: typescript, solidity, typechain

Before I introduced typechain to a project, I passed `Buffer` to a smart contract that accepted `bytes`. Now types for that method expect `string` and I need to do

```js
`0x{buffer.toString('hex')}`
```

Is there a way around this? [Here](https://github.com/kuco23/address-from-public-key-in-solidity/blob/master/test/publicKeyToAddress.test.ts#L59) is the repo.